# How to make a line before and after my h1 tag?

Tags: html, css

I've search around for a bit to find a solution on how I can make something like this:

----------- My text --------------
In HTML/CSS. So I need a hr tag before and after my text.

Anyone know how this can be fixed?

Comment: I answered the exact same question yesterday. Have a look at [How to style in HR on left and right hand side of div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015309/how-to-style-in-hr-on-left-and-right-hand-side-of-div/9015330#9015330)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Inline HR</title>
<style type="text/css">
div {
    text-align: center;
}

hr {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="center">
<hr>
My Text
<hr>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cKrqK/

However, if you are not happy that the HR's don't extend all the way to the edges of the page due to `40%` width, this is how you can solve it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Text on HR</title>
<style type="text/css">
.text {
    position: relative;
    top: -1em;
    text-align: center;
}

.text span {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<hr>
<div class="text">
<span>
My text
</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EdtwL/

The second example, places your text with a white background (change it to whatever background your page has) on the HR and center-aligns it with `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto`.

Comment: how do you center the text ? Currently it's not aligned center

Answer (score 2):

You could create an image, set it to repeat like so:

```
h1 {
background-image: url('line.png');
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
text-align: center;
}
h1 span {
background-color: #FFF  //Or your website background color if not white

//UPDATE: to add padding around the text:
padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

Then in HTML:

```
<h1><span>My text</span></h1>
```

Comment: How can I make a padding around the text with your example?
So there isn't any line behind the text?

Comment: I've upated the example above to add padding to the span tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
div{
    position:relative;
    height:10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}


span{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-10px;
    background-color:white;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>

<span>My Text</span>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
h1:before {
    padding-right: 5px;
    content: "---------------------";
}
h1:after {
padding-left: 5px;
    content: "---------------------";
}
```

If you really want a line and not dashes, then I don't have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple!

```
h2 { text-align: center; /*optional*/ line-height: 2; background: #ccc; }
h2:before,
h2:after { padding: 1em; position: relative; top: -.4em; content: '__________________'; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xhj1poj0/