# what is the HTML & CSS code for text between two lines?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to style in HR on left and right hand side of div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015309/how-to-style-in-hr-on-left-and-right-hand-side-of-div)
>   [How to make a line before and after my h1 tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033823/how-to-make-a-line-before-and-after-my-h1-tag)

I need to do something like that in HTML and CSS.

The Format

"-------------------- MY Footer ------------------------------"

I need to make it at the center of my screen using HTML and CSS.

Comment: Goodness! What a coincidence :-) Thanks T.J.

Answer (score 0):

Exampe: (CSS for 'footer')

```
margin: 0 auto;
width: 600px;
```

Answer (score 0):

a div with .centered {width: 100% , text-align:center } as the css class
And if the css property text-align: center doesn't work you can use the one from below

You can use a div, with a class like the one from below 
.center{
Left: 50%
}
that way you can have aligned in the center of the screen

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center the text then use `text-align: center;` if you want to center the div where the text is than first give the div - container a width e.g: `width: 200px;` than set `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: I came here to find out how to get text to break up a line like this: ----------Breaking the Line----------------------------. like at the top of a box to show a new section of the page. Any Ideas?