# How to do centered <h1> with <hr/> on both sides over a background image

Tags: html, css, background-image

How do I create centered `<h1>` with `<hr/>` on both sides ***over a background image***?

I also need it to handle various text lengths, scale well for mobile viewing and have the `<hr/>` go to 100% width of its container.

I want this look, but over a background image.
[image: text on solid background]

There are lots of answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2812770/242), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9033823/242) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9015309/242) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12648513/242)) for text with lines on either side but all of them rely on using a solid background colour behind the text, which doesn't work for me as the page I want to put this on has a background image.

Here is how I achieve the look above, which handles various lengths of text and scales well:

**CSS**

```
.title-box {
    height: 2px; 
    background-color: rgb(215, 0, 0); 
    text-align: center;
}
.title-outer {
    background-color:rgb(230, 230, 230); 
    position: relative; 
    top: -0.7em;
}
.title-inner {
    margin:0px 20px; 
    font-size: 17.5px; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    color:rgb(100, 100, 100);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="title-box">
    <span class="title-outer">
        <span class="title-inner">OUR STORY</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I have tried the method below and it *kind of* works but it doesn't handle various text widths or scale well due to the `<h1>` and the `<hr/>`s being in seperate `<div>`s:

[image: text on background image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4"><hr /></div>
    <div class="span4"><h4>OUR STORY</h4></div>
    <div class="span4"><hr /></div>
</div>
```

*Note: This is example is using the Bootstrap grid system but that is not part of the problem/solution.*

So any ideas how I can get the same look and behaviour but without the backgound colour for the text so it can sit over a background image?

Comment: Well, I have an idea, but it doesn't handle various text width.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović Yeah, without handling various text widths it's not solving my problem.  Thanks though.

Comment: You can include jQuery though.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović Post up your solution and I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code was posted originally by [Arbel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2210457/arbel) but his/her answer disappeared for some reason?  I am reposting it (including some mods I've made) because it was the solution I ended up using. Credit where credit is due.

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pA5Gu/

**HTML**

```
<div class="title-box"> 
    <fieldset class="title-outer">
            <legend id="titleInner" class="title-inner">OUR STORY</legend>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.title-box { 
    background-image: url('http://imagezo.com/images/1302-green-bubbles-awesome-background-wallpaper.jpg');
    height:100%;
}
.title-outer {
    border-top:2px solid rgb(215, 0, 0);
    background-color: transparent;
}
.title-inner {
    width:auto;
    padding:0px 20px;
    border: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 17.5px; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var legendWidth = $('#titleInner').outerWidth();
    var margin = 'calc((100% - '+legendWidth+'px) / 2)';
    $('#titleInner').css('margin-left', margin);
    $('#titleInner').css('margin-right', margin);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

No need JS, here is a pure CSS solution.

**CSS**

```
.title-hr hr {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 5px 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="title-hr"><hr />My Title<hr /></h5>
```

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/yptmftr4/

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've played a bit with this code and here is my solution. Yes, it's a bit dirty because I've used `:before` and `:after`, but works.

**HTML**

```
<div class="title-box">
    <span id="first" class="title-inner">OUR LOOOoo oooo oOONG STORY</span>
</div>
<div class="title-box">
    <span id="second" class="title-inner">OUR STORY</span>
</div>
<div class="title-box">
    <span id="third" class="title-inner">STORY</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.title-box {
    text-align: center;
}
.title-inner {
    margin:0px 20px;
    font-size: 17.5px;
    font-weight:bold;
    position: relative;
    color:rgb(100, 100, 100);
}
.title-inner:after, .title-inner:before {
    content:"";
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;
    height: 2px;
    background: red;
}
.title-inner:before {
    float: left;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function work() {
        $(".title-inner").each(function () {
            var full_width = $(window).width();
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var title_width = $("#" + id).width();
            var new_width = (full_width - title_width) / 2 - 40;
            $('head').append("<style>#" + id + ":before, #" + id + ":after{width:" + new_width + "px !important;}</style>");
        });
    }
    work();
    $(window).resize(function () {
        work();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ffb3X/4/

Because `:before` and `:after` are not part of DOM, I've used `.append()` function to append style tags in head for every title.

This code will on page load calculate everything, so it's responsive.

Comment: +1 Thanks for posting this up.  Interesting approach to use :before and :after.  I have only recently become aware of those but never used them.  See the [answer I posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16028515/242) (Note: Arbel wrote that code) which produces similar results but without having to reload the page.

Comment: @DavidHAust, :before and :after are aswesome :) Also, look at my updated jsfiddle, I've added .resize() function, so now there is no need to reload page. But remember - this is only for demo, because there is no need for that on site. Responsive site will get viewport on page load, users will not resize their viewports.

Comment: Actually, users **will** resize their viewports, because they have portrait and landscape view on tablets and mobile phones :)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Will definitely be using :before and :after in the future.  I've ended up going with Arbel's solution.  HTML has one more element that yours but the CSS and JS are a bit tidier.  Cheers again.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/habo/HrfuH/1/

```
<div class="title-box">
    <div class="myContent">
    <div class="title-outer"><hr /></div>
    <div class="title-inner "><h4>OUR STORY</h4></div>
    <div class="title-outer"><hr /></div>
    </div>
</div>


.myContent{
    display:block;
    width:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.title-box {
    background:#eee;
    height:60px;
}
.title-outer{

}

hr {
    height: 2px;
    background-color:rgb(215, 0, 0);
    margin: 2em 0;
    width:25%;
    float:left;
}

.title-inner {
    margin:0px 20px; 
    font-size: 17.5px; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    color:rgb(100, 100, 100);
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks HaBo but I am trying to avoid hard coding the widths.  Looking for something more dynamic. Arbel and Miljan suggested using jQuery to calculte the widths which is looking like it could work.

Comment: agreed. it looks better way of handling this.