# Convert CSS calc() function to jQuery for expanded browser support

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following code used to [solve this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027223/how-to-do-centered-h1-with-hr-on-both-sides-over-a-background-image/16028515#16028515) I had.  It works in IE9/Chrome:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var legendWidth = $('#titleInner').outerWidth();
        var margin = 'calc((100% - ' + legendWidth + 'px) / 2)';
        $('#titleInner').css('margin-left', margin);
        $('#titleInner').css('margin-right', margin);
    });
```

However, I would like to get rid of the [CSS calc() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) so that it works in IE7/8.

I had seen [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117216/css-width-calc100-100px-alternative-using-jquery) using jQuery to do the calculations which seems like a good solution.

Problem is I can't get the syntax/chaining working.

Here is what I have tried:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var legendWidth = $('#titleInner').outerWidth();
        $('#titleInner').css('margin-left', '100%').css('margin-left', '-' + legendWidth + 'px').css('margin-left', '/2');
        $('#titleInner').css('margin-right', '100%').css('margin-right', '-' + legendWidth + 'px').css('margin-right', '/2');
    });
```

I have tried a few variations (removing the 'px', etc) but no luck.  I also couldn't figure out how to add parens to scope the '/2' across multiple [chain elements](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/).

So, can anyone please help with the jQuery equivalent to `var margin = 'calc((100% - ' + legendWidth + 'px) / 2)';` ?

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var legendWidth = $('#titleInner').outerWidth();
    var legendParentWidth = $('#titleInner').parent().outerWidth();
    var margin = (legendParentWidth - legendWidth) / 2;
    $('#titleInner').css('margin-left', margin + 'px');
    $('#titleInner').css('margin-right', margin + 'px');
});
```

Or with chaining:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var legendWidth = $('#titleInner').outerWidth();
    $('#titleInner').css('margin-left', '100%').css('margin-left', function(){
        return (($('#titleInner').css('margin-left') - legendWidth) / 2) + 'px';
    });
    $('#titleInner').css('margin-right', '100%').css('margin-right', function(){
        return (($('#titleInner').css('margin-right') - legendWidth) / 2) + 'px';
    });
});
```

Comment: Good idea.  Works in IE9 but not IE7/8 unfortunately.

Comment: @DavidHAust Quick question: Are you using the 2.x release of jQuery?

Comment: No, the 1.8.1 release. You think that would make a difference?

Comment: Yes, the 2.x release doesn't work on IE6/7/8 at all... So if you were using that, it would explain why my code didn't work ;)

Comment: Your chaining version doesn't work either.  Forces content off the right side of page.  Does the chaining get evaluated left-to-right?

Comment: re: 2.x.  hehe.  Wish that was my problem ; )

Comment: @DavidHAust What margin values are given to `#titleInner` after this code is run? (Also, chaining should be evaluated left-to-right...)

Comment: When run with your chaining, left and right are both 100% according to IE9 DevTools.

Comment: It's like the function in the second chain element returns zero, or it's not being evaluated correctly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30670/discussion-between-david-haust-and-simon-m)